# C# how to retrieve data of List in a method

Tags: c#

I have a method that gets data of students:

```
    public static List<Student> getStudentInfo()
    {

        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        students.Add(new Student(1, "Doe", "John", "someData"));
        students.Add(new Student(2, "Pit", "Brat", "someData1"));
        students.Add(new Student(5, "Kardasian", "Kim", "someData2"));
        students.Add(new Student(4, "Lee", "Chun", "someData"));
        .
        .
        return students;
    }

    foreach (Student s in students)
     Console.WriteLine(s);
```

I am trying to create a method that retrieves the data above using `foreach (Student s in students) Console.WriteLine(s);`
, but I cannot get and print the data.

How do I access the list in a method?

Comment: "but I cannot get and print the data": please provide details.

Comment: @ScottHunter I am learning sorting using IComperable, and I want to retrieve the data in List and see how sorting works. but I cannot retrieve the data.

Comment: You cannot print the Student data because the Student class has no ToString method and you're not printing separate fields from the object, but just the whole object.

Answer (score 6):

## Option 1. Override `ToString()`

Please see [How to: Override the ToString Method (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)

> ```
> class Person
> {
>    public string Name { get; set; }
>    public int Age { get; set; }
>
>
>    public override string ToString()
>    {
>        return "Person: " + Name + " " + Age;
>    }
> }
> ```

## Option 2. Print the fields separately

```
foreach (Student s in students)
     Console.WriteLine($"{s.Id} {s.SomeData}");
```

---

```
var students = getStudentInfo();
foreach (Student s in students)
Console.WriteLine(s); // `Student` doesn't override ToString(), this will be the name of the class.

foreach (Student s in students)
Console.WriteLine($"{s.Id}, {s.Name}");
```

Output

```
Program+Student
Program+Student
Program+Student
Program+Student
1, Doe
2, Pit
5, Kardasian
4, Lee
```

Comment: given the ambiguity of the question, this could be a viable answer.. but that's really only based on that ambiguity.

Comment: Hopefully we're still better than the AI assistants, in some respects at least ;)

Comment: @tymtam thank you so much for the clear explanation. It helped my understanding.